# vertical Missalignment with inline-block (other elements pushed down)

Tags: alignment, css

This issue has been answered before. Sadly, `vertical-align: top` does not fix the problem for me.
Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CPAtE/2/

How can i vertically align my inline-block DIVs (to the top) ?

Comment: got it: applying `vertical-align: top` to the children fixes the misalignment. I have no clue why this should be applied to the children though...

Comment: but my answer just beat you to it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top;` in your .slide class

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/CPAtE/4/)**